# How inline comments bypassing SQL Injection Web Application Firewalls?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-injection, union, firewall

A normal UNION based SQL Injection can be blocked using the WAF, which filter keywords like `UNION, SELECT`. But I've that it can be bypassed by the inline comment statements of SQL such as `/*!UNION*/` and `/*!SELECT*/`

Comment statements are meant for only reading purpose, right? If so, how a SQL server reads the injection query inside the comments and executes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering keywords with a WAF is pointless. There is no way it could possibly succeed. Take a look at this list of ways to bypass it: http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/ (And I found that link in just a few seconds with google.)

If the code was written correctly, it would not be necessary.

As for your question the `/*!` syntax of MySQL is for MySQL specific commands. It's intended for you to be able to write portable SQL (that can run on any database) and yet still be able to send MySQL special commands.

Comment: Thanks for the cheat sheet, However I've something in same genre already. Can you more elaborate the second part of your answer? If it's a special kind of query, then it will execute a valid query and ignore the notes to developer?

Comment: @William.Ebe I found this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html which mentions that it exists, but does not document all the possible things that go there.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection should not be an issue at all if you're using a database driver that supports placeholders for data. What you'd be trying to do with an after-the-fact detection is futile, like trying to eradicate a roach infestation with a ratty fly-swatter. You can't possibly get them all.

The best practice is to ensure it's impossible to inject hostile data into your queries in the first place. There are [many examples available on Booby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) that illustrate how to do this properly.

Comment: My actual question is about MySQL, I guess. Just wondering how the comments are executed.

Comment: As far as I know, these are converted from comments to live code by the `mysql` command line tool based on the version number tagged with them if the examples spiked into a `mysqldump` database snapshot are any example.

Comment: Well this wasn't understandable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out partial query by not closing them can be used for bypassing blacklisting, removing spaces, obfuscating and determining database versions.

The one that you've mentioned is a special comment syntax for MySQL. If you put a code into this comments it's going to execute in MySQL only. Also you can use this to execute some code only if the server is higher than supplied version. For example:

Classical Inline Comment SQL Injection Attack Samples

```
ID: /*!32302 10*/
ID: 10
```

You will get the same response if MySQL version is higher than 3.23.02